# XR device (Oculus) starts unpaired in Unity's new input system

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, virtual-reality

I've set up actions in Unity's new input system and added corresponding bindings for both keyboard and XR (Oculus Rift). When I enter play mode, the keyboard-based action correctly fires, but the button clicks from the Rift controller do not.

Viewing the Input Debug panel, I see that User #0 is showing a control scheme of Keyboard/Mouse and that the Rift is not listed as a **Paired Device**:

[image: Debug Panel]

`InputUser.PerformPairingWithDevice` appears in the Input docs, but given that I'm just doing a local single-player experience, it makes me think that I'm missing an easier way to set this up. Is there a way to alter the default user paired input to include the Rift?

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Took me quite a few days to figure out. Trying out your mentioned function and hope XR Input actually works now.

Comment: Alright, I solved my problem. I accidentally added another PlayerInput component somewhere else in my scene, so Input System (rightly) thought I was making a multiplayer experience.